# script to loop URLs check load time and StatusCode

Tags: powershell

im a bit stuck with this **powershell** script.

I have a IIS 10 webserver with multiple application under the default website.

I need to loop through some of the apps, check if it responds in 3 sec time frame and check if it returns a StatusCode=200. 
if not than recycle the applicationPool of the "problematic" app and return the "StateCritical" status.

Im doing somthing wrong obviously as this is not working properly. any suggestions?

```
$StateOK = 0
$StateCritical = 2

$infTable = @{
 URL1 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname1.svc'
 URL2 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname2.svc'
 URL3 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname3.svc'
 URL4 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname4.svc'
 URL5 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname5.svc'   
}
foreach ($key in $infTable.GetEnumerator()) {
           $M = Measure-Command -Expression {(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $($key.Value))
           if ($M.TotalMilliseconds -gt 3000 ){
                    write-host "$($key.Name) is not available"
                    Restart-WebAppPool -Name $($key.Name)
                    return $StateCritical  
            }

            elseif ($M.TotalMilliseconds -lt 3000 ){
                    write-host "$($key.Name) is OK"
                    return $StateOK  
            }
}}
```

Comment: Inside of your expression, just assign `$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $key.Value`. Then check `$response.StatusCode` in your `if-else` block.

Comment: the problem is that when one of the URLs is not responding, the script is stuck on that URL. I need a way to tell the script to try for 3 seconds and if there is no response, return 'StateCritical'

Comment: Try with `Invoke-Webrequest -Timeoutsec 3`.

Comment: I just noticed that Im getting statusCode 200 for all URLs. even if it does not answer or give error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this still interests someone, I managed to solve this with help from [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Script-for-13a551b3)

```
$infTable = @{
    URL1 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname1.svc'
    URL2 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname2.svc'
    URL3 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname3.svc'
    URL4 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname4.svc'
    URL5 = 'http://myServer/sub/appname5.svc'
}

 $Result = @()

  foreach ($key in $infTable.GetEnumerator()) {
      $time = try{
      $request = $null
       ## Request the URI, and measure how long the response took.
      $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $($key.Value) -TimeoutSec 4 }
      $result1.TotalMilliseconds
      } 
      catch
      {
       <# If the request generated an exception (i.e.: 500 server
       error or 404 not found), we can pull the status code from the
       Exception.Response property #>
       $request = $_.Exception.Response
       $request
       $time = -1
      }  
  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{
  Time = Get-Date;
  #Uri = $uri;
  Uri = $($key.Value);
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode;
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription;
  ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength;
  TimeTaken =  $time; 
  }

}
    #Prepare email body in HTML format
if($result -ne $null)
{
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B></TD</TR>"
    Foreach($Entry in $Result)
    { 
        if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200")
        {
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>"
        }

        elseif($Entry.StatusCode -eq "500")
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=purple>"
        }
        else
        {
            $Outputreport += "<TR>"
        }
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>"
    }
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"
}

$Outputreport | out-file C:\Test.htm
Invoke-Expression C:\Test.htm
```